# How to validate a list of arbitrary URLS?

Tags: ios, security, app-transport-security

So I have a list of thousands of URLs that can be accessed in my app, many of which are insecure (ATS is currently turned off), also some of which redirect to several other URLs. What I need to do is find some way of automating this process to spit out a list of insecure links. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to turn ATS off.  In iOS 10 you can use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` if your insecure urls are only in a web view, but if your app runs on versions earlier than iOS 10 then disabling ATS is the only real option.  I would focus on creating exceptions for domains where you know TLS is available and important (e.g. servers where you are using APIs)

Comment: Need to support back to iOS 8. I think I am going to try to write a command line app that validates urls.

Comment: That sounds pretty fragile; what happens if one of those web sites changes after you release your app?  I would disable ATS and be done.

Comment: It's not going to be an app, it's going to be a command line script that runs on a cron job that pulls a list of URLS and parses them. I just hope a Cocoa Webview and UIWebView follow the same ATS restrictions.

Comment: But aren't you going to use the script to build a list of exceptions for your iOS app?  The ATS exceptions are in the Info.plist so you can't update it without releasing a new version of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You could script the nscurl call to run through the URLs.  Basically, with a list of urls in a txt file like so:

**urls.txt**

```
https://www.apple.com
https://www.reddit.com
http://snopes.com
http://www.yahoo.com
https://www.google.com
```

you could create a script

**ats_check.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh 

while read URL
do
    nscurl --ats-diagnostics ${URL} 2>/dev/null > ats_results.txt

    if  grep -q "Result : FAIL" ats_results.txt; then
        echo "${URL} failed ATS checks. run 'nscurl --ats-diagnostics ${URL}' for more details."
    else
        # echo "${URL} passed ATS checks."
        echo "."
    fi
done < urls.txt

rm ats_results.txt
```

Basically, if it fails ANY test in the nscurl call, it will display the URL.

Note that nscurl requires Mac OS 10.11 or later.

Comment: Also, this may take a while to run since the ATS checks can take a while, especially on slower sites.  I added a dot for the ones that pass successfully, but you can take the whole else block out if you just want a print our of the failing urls.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing a CLI app that uses a WebView to load all URLS in my data file and dumping all URLS that error to a text file.

Comment: Did my script not work for you?  It basically does what you need without having to write an app. Your app  won't help others on stack overflow in the future unless you publish the source and provide a link.

Comment: @wottle While your script is great, what I need is a bit more complex. Basically my tool will look in the current directory, sort all the csv files by date and use the newest one as it's input file. The tool will then spin up 20 webviews to start checking URLs pulled from a serialized queue of data extracted from the data file that include the URL and associated GUID. After the data gets processed, the tool outputs the invalid url, GUID and all redirects to the non-secure URL. While all of this could probably be done via shell script, nobody on my team would be able to maintain it.

Comment: @wottle As soon as I am finished, I will look into open sourcing the tool for others to use.

Comment: OK, that is definitely more complicated than you had in your original post. Good luck with the project.

Comment: @wottle Thanks. The scope has definitely expanded since the initial post. Go figure ;)